# How to increase the speed of the application (Hotel booking system) when we integreate multiple Hotel APIs

Tags: php

I am working on Hotel booking system. I have to integrate 5 Hotel APIs to get the Hotels. I have seen few
application which are having multiple APIs. These applications has the process as

1 Running the hotel availability requests(one by one)

1. Parsing the xml response and inset the details into database
2. Showing the twenty to thirty hotels per page(We can see other hotels with the help of pagination)

But these projects are very very slow. These applications are taking 1.30-3 minutes to display the hotels

I have two rough ideas.

1) I will run one API(Which is very faster among my API) and show the result first, and then i will run other APIs. In this case i should update the pagination
(But i dont know properly how to implement this).

2) I may increase the speed with multi treading (cURL is supporting multi treading).

Please suggest ideas to increase the speed of my application.

Technologies i am using: PHP, Mysql, cURL/SOAP, Simple XML Parsing(In steed of DOM Parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your webserver requesting xml data from the hotel APIs & parsing the response on *every* browser request? If so then this sounds very inefficient - I would have made a background process set to repeat every 5 minutes or so to fetch, parse & store the data in the database, then your webserver can simply present this data from the database instead of from the external services.

Comment: Only one time i am executing the curl and storing the data into db. This is happening when user click on the search button after filling his search parameters. Process is like search->running the hotel api,parsing and storing(next page)->showing the result(next page)

Comment: Imagine the scenario when, say, 20 people click that search button at the same time - do you want your application requesting hotel data 20 times from the various hotel APIs? How slow do you want your server to go, exactly? With my solution your application only needs to access the latest data in the local database that was pulled by the background process - the only drawback being you might have data which is a mere 5 minutes out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Install [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) on your test environment, and use the profiler to see where the bottlenecks are. There is a nice add-on called [KCachegrind](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/profiling-Xdebug-KCacheGrind/Jason_Gilmore12302010.php3) that show exactly where your CPU cycles are wasted.